# How to visualize a Regression Tree in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm looking to visualize a **regression** tree built using any of the ensemble methods in scikit learn (gradientboosting regressor, random forest regressor,bagging regressor).
[I've looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835199/scikit-learn-decision-trees-regression-retrieve-all-samples-for-leaf-not-mean) which comes close, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn)
which deals with classifier trees. But these questions require the 'tree' method, which is not available to the regression models in SKLearn.

but it didn't seem to yield a result. 
I'm running into issues because there is no `.tree` method for the regression versions of these trees (the method only exists for the classification versions).
I'd like an output resembling [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460595/how-do-i-make-a-regression-tree-like-this) but based on a sci kit learn-constructed tree.

I've explored the methods associated with the objects but just cannot produce an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualizing decision tree in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: Again, that is a decision tree, not a regression tree, the methods of the functions are not the same.

Comment: I think you're a little confused... You mean that changing the `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()` of that question with `tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()` won't do the job? Or you are only interested in trees of an *ensemble* (in which case you have poorly formulated your question subject)?

Comment: The `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` function is not limited to `DecisionTreeClassifiers`. You can equally use it with the regression equivalent.

Comment: @desertnaut; my apologies. You are correct. This question was indeed a duplicate, and the answer you pointed me to solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I commented, there is no functional difference between a classification and a regression decision tree plot. Adapting the regression toy example from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-regression):

```python
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
y = [0.5, 2.5]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

and then, similarly, some code from the classification [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) regarding `graphviz`:

```python
import graphviz 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot')
```

we end up with a file `tree.dot`, looking like that:

```python
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="X[0] <= 1.0\nmse = 1.0\nsamples = 2\nvalue = 1.5"] ;
1 [label="mse = 0.0\nsamples = 1\nvalue = 0.5"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="mse = 0.0\nsamples = 1\nvalue = 2.5"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
}
```

Now, you can proceed to visualize it as shown in the docs - but if for whatever reason you cannot render Graphviz objects, you can use the handy service [WebGraphviz](http://webgraphviz.com/) (+1 to the [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn/41602728#41602728) in the linked question); the result looks like this:

[image]

Your own answer, i.e. going all the way to install `graphlab` just for the visualization, sounds like overkill...

Last remark: don't get deceived by the superficial differences in the tree layouts, which reflect only design choices of the respective visualization packages; the regression tree you have plotted (which, admittedly, does not look much like a *tree*) is structurally similar to the classification one taken from the docs - simply imagine a top-down tree, with your `odor` node at the top, followed by your green nodes and terminating to your blue & orange nodes (and replace "yes/no" with "True/False")...

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found software offered by Turi that models a *regression* tree, not to be confused with a *decision* tree.
[Hope this helps](https://turi.com/learn/userguide/supervised-learning/decision_tree_regression.html)

For what its worth, a regression tree looks like this:
[image]

While a decision/classifier tree looks like this:
[image]

And tho they look the same, the attribute needed to create this is `tree_` which is only available to [classifiers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), not [regressors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).

Comment: Still, you seem confused... You link to a *decision tree* classifier vs a *random forest* regressor... [Decision trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) come to both classifier & regressor versions...

Comment: This has now been open sourced by Apple, called Turi Create

Answer (score 0):

DTR will sort of create a partition level for all the values
Check the graph - [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEnyu.png)

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

#Getting X and y variable
X = df.iloc[:,1:2].values
y =df.iloc[:,2].values

#Creating a model object and fiting the data
reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
reg.fit(X,y)

# Visualising the Decision Tree Regression results (higher resolution)
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.01)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid, reg.predict(X_grid), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Decision Tree Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

**A simple text mode solution**:

```
from sklearn import tree
print(tree.export_text(clf_model))
```

typical result:

```
|--- feature_3 <= 0.46
|   |--- feature_0 <= 0.50
|   |   |--- feature_7 <= 0.50
|   |   |   |--- feature_5 <= 0.78
|   |   |   |   |--- value: [3288.64]
etc...
```

use `clf_model.feature_names_in_` to get feature names

credits to https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-decision-tree/